# Is there a way to set the context of ajax callbacks to always be the the scope of whatever called the ajax function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

is there a way to do this?  I can set it for one ajax call using the ajax option: {context: this}, but how would I do it so that I can set it up in $.ajaxSetup?  Thx!

Comment: The title is not the place to put the main question. Put the actual question in the question body instead. Please remove "Thx" and such words, and add proper capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default of Javascript callbacks; the default scope is calling scope.

Comment: what about in the context of $.ajax?  The context is the ajax settings object right?